# Rails Pre-building Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have a simple Parent/Child relation between (example) model "Survey" and model "Question".

In the Survey model, I have implemented `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions`, and everything is working fine there.

When creating a new Survey, I wanted a few question fields to be shown on the page, so I did this with

```
# survey_controller.rb
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times { @survey.questions.build }
end
```

This works great as well.

My problem is that when I submit the form, and there are validation errors, the form now shows the 3 questions IN ADDITION to the pre-filled, erroneous fields. For example, if 2 of the 3 question fields were invalid and I submit the form, after the page reloads and I see the validation errors, I now see 3 blank question fields PLUS the 3 pre-filled fields (a total of 6 showing on screen).

How can I ensure that only a total number (3) of questions are shown on the NEW and EDIT forms when using this `3.times  { @survey.questions.build }` technique? Or should I do it another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you do something like `(3-@survey.questions.count).times...` (so if there's already a count of 3, the `times` loop will not execute). Does that solve the issue at all?

Comment: Submitting the form request the 'create' or 'update' action, not 'new'. Puzzling that 'new' seems to be executed as well...